# I want to do sub groups in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have a dataframe as below I want to do first group by trip_number and then subgroup by mode.

```
trip_number         mode    Km          time
    1               0       10      2021-10-01 01:44:50+00:00   
    1               0       10      2021-10-01 01:44:51+00:00
    1               0       10      2021-10-01 01:44:52+00:00
    1               1       10.2    2021-10-01 01:44:53+00:00
    1               1       10.3    2021-10-01 01:44:54+00:00
    1               1       10.5    2021-10-01 01:44:55+00:00
    1               1       11      2021-10-01 01:44:56+00:00
    1               1       11.2    2021-10-01 01:44:57+00:00
    1               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:44:58+00:00
    1               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:44:59+00:00
    1               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:00+00:00
    1               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:01+00:00
    2               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:02+00:00
    2               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:03+00:00
    2               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:04+00:00   
    2               0       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:05+00:00
    2               1       11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:06+00:00
    2               1       11.5    2021-10-01 01:45:07+00:00
    2               1       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:08+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:09+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:10+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:11+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:12+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:13+00:00
    2               0       11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:14+00:00
```

Can someone please help me or guide me how can I achieve this.
The output data frame I want is to like this:

```
trip_number     mode    startkm     endkm           starttime                   endtime                     subtrip
    1           0       10          10      2021-10-01 01:44:50+00:00       2021-10-01 01:44:52+00:00           1
    1           1       10.2        11.2    2021-10-01 01:44:53+00:00       2021-10-01 01:44:57+00:00           2
    1           0       11.2        11.2    2021-10-01 01:44:58+00:00       2021-10-01 01:45:01+00:00           3
    2           0       11.2        11.2    2021-10-01 01:45:02+00:00       2021-10-01 01:45:05+00:00           1
    2           1       11.2        11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:06+00:00       2021-10-01 01:45:08+00:00           2
    2           0       11.6        11.6    2021-10-01 01:45:09+00:00       2021-10-01 01:45:14+00:00           3
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not belong to data science as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would have to create a column that indicates the subtrip, this can be done by comparing the value for the mode column with the value in the row before it. You can then simply group on the `trip_number`, `subtrip`, and `mode` columns and aggregate to get the minimum and maximum for the columns you need.

```
(
    df
    # compare value for mode column with previous row
    .assign(subtrip = lambda x: (x["mode"] != x.groupby("trip_number")["mode"].shift(1))) 
    # use cumsum() to get the subtrip number within each group
    .assign(subtrip = lambda x: x.groupby("trip_number")["subtrip"].transform(pd.Series.cumsum))
    .groupby(["trip_number", "subtrip", "mode"])
    .agg(
        startkm = ("Km", "min"),
        endkm = ("Km", "max"),
        starttime = ("time", "min"),
        endtime = ("time", "max"),
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

| trip_number | subtrip | mode | startkm | endkm | starttime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 10 | 2021-10-01 01:44:50+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:44:52+00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 10.2 | 11.2 | 2021-10-01 01:44:53+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:44:57+00:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 11.2 | 11.2 | 2021-10-01 01:44:58+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:45:01+00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 11.2 | 11.2 | 2021-10-01 01:45:02+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:45:05+00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 11.2 | 11.6 | 2021-10-01 01:45:06+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:45:08+00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 11.6 | 11.6 | 2021-10-01 01:45:09+00:00 | 2021-10-01 01:45:14+00:00 |

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  the above scenario is different and the scenario what you gave is different.

Comment: @udaykumargajavalli I edited my answer to use the data you provided and make use of the `subtrip` column.

Comment: Thanks for the code @Oxbowerce